# How to run the make command for mocha test for node.js application

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have created a folder : **MyFirstNodeAppl** and within that, I created a **test** folder which contains all the tests that need to run using the mocha framework.

I also created a make file named as **MakeFile** and the content details as mentioned below:

```
test:
      @./node_modules/.bin/mocha -u tdd

.PHONY: test
```

**package.json** is in the same level as test and **MakeFile** with the content as mentioned below:

```
{
    "name": "nockmarket", 
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery" : "1.7.3",
        "mocha": "1.3.0",
        "should": "1.0.0"     
    }
}
```

After setting up the above things, I ran the npm install command using the node command prompt window. Now as I know that Mocha uses make to run the test harness, And for windows users we need Cygwin so I installed it in my system. But I am not able to run the make command in order to test the unit test cases.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue by providing guidance to me in the above.

Folder structure details :
[image]

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to run mocha on your tests is to execute:

```
npm install -g mocha
```

Which should make the mocha binary available on your path. Then, from cygwin, just run `mocha` from the root directory of your project. That will cause it to execute all the tests in *.js files under the test directory.

Comment: Works, thanks!  But doesn't seem to execute tests under subdirectories of `test`.  Any way to get Mocha to do so?

Comment: Found it!  This is accomplished by specifying "--recursive" on the command line or via mocha.opts (http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#mocha.opts)

Answer (score 2):

Install Mocha module in your app or globally:

```
  npm install --save mocha
```

its saves mocha dependency in your package.json file.

npm puts aliases to all the binaries in your dependencies on that special folder. Finally, npm will add node_modules/.bin to the PATH automatically when running an npm script, so in your package.json you can do just:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
 }
```

and invoke it with

```
 npm test
```

Comment: Should be `--save-dev`, don't think you want mocha in production code